# Include external stylesheets internally for email templates

Tags: html, css, email, stylesheet, jinja2

I'm trying to craft some nice email templates for my site, but I'm having a conflict between my desire for well-crafted code and functionality.

My problem is that all of my email templates are formatted like standard templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"...>
    </head>
    <body>
        Some stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

which displays just fine as a webpage, but in trying to send this as a formatted email, it's essentially just sending the `Some stuff` section, which means none of the formatting really makes it across.

My current emailing code looks like this:

```
message = Message(
    subject="Subject",
    html= render_template(
        'emails/confirmation_email.html',
        confirmation_code=confirmation.confirmation_code
    ),
    sender = ("sender", "sender@gmail.com")
)
```

I'm using Jinja2 templates and the Flask-Mail extension.

Basically, I really want to include these stylesheets in my email, but I really object to including everything in a style tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inline your CSS in HTML email. This is because some email clients (Gmail for example) strip your `<style>` tags. Here is the [list of support](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) (click the pdf link for the full chart).

There are [several CSS inlining tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code/17882057#17882057) to make your job easier If you prefer to work traditionally within the `<style>` tag. You should never place your CSS in an external file however.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't include external resources in html emails.

You will have to include the css inside every mail separately using `<style>...</style>`

Comment: Are you aware of any jinja tools that might do this automatically? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: No, to be honest I dont know the jinja tools. I just know something about automated mail sending (in C#)